# Syntax Accessing Invalid DataTable Index

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I have 4 datatables in my syntax.  I want to ignore `ds.Tables[0];` and iterate 1, 2 and 3.  The syntax below throws an error of

> Can not find table 4

I thought that the `ds.Tables.Count;` would show that there were only 3 datatables (since it is a 0 based index).  But instead it continues to try to process and throws the above error.

Am I misunderstanding how this process works?  What should I do in order to only process datatables 1, 2, 3?

(I have the syntax initially set to `int i = 1;` so that the code begins processing with `ds.Tables[1];`

```
for (int i= 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the bug is in code you are not showing as Test.Count would be 3 if you had 3 tables. And your for loop therefore would execute 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to verify that you're actually adding four DataTables into your DataSet.  I created the test code below and it worked as expected.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); // 0
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); // 1
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); // 2
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable()); // 3
for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    var currentTable = ds.Tables[i];
    if (currentTable == null)
    {
        Response.Write("Table is null!");
    }
}
```

My code iterated through the loop starting at Table 2 (Index 1), Table 3 (Index 2), and Table 4 (Index 3).  I would double check that you're DataSet does contain 4 DataTables.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have confirmed I have 4 DataTables.  I want to ignore index[0] and only process 1, 2, 3.  Let me edit to add more code.